# better way to find max date inside big pool of core data objects

Tags: cocoa, core-data

i have big pool of core date objects (around 10000) and there is too long time doing code according profile:
    NSDate *maxExternalChangedDate = [codes valueForKeyPath:@"@max.externalChangedDate"];
is community know better way to found it?

```
NSString *rateSheetID = [rateSheetAndPrefix valueForKey:@"rateSheetID"];
NSFetchRequest *requestCodesForSale = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[requestCodesForSale setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CodesvsDestinationsList"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.moc]];
[requestCodesForSale setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K.carrier.GUID == %@)",relationshipName,carrierGUID]];
NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *codes = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:requestCodesForSale error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"Failed to executeFetchRequest to data store: %@ in function:%@", [error localizedDescription],NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)); 

NSNumber *count = [codes valueForKeyPath:@"@count.externalChangedDate"];
if (count == 0) { 
    [requestCodesForSale release];
    [pool drain], pool = nil;
    return YES;
}
NSDate *maxExternalChangedDate = [codes valueForKeyPath:@"@max.externalChangedDate"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `NSFetchRequest` and returning `NSDictionaryResultType` You can use `NSExpressionDescription` to yeild the results for functions like max() and min().

Sample Code from Apple

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"salary"];
NSExpression *maxSalaryExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:"
                                                  arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"maxSalary"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:maxSalaryExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
```

Check out this doc for more information.

[Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

In theory this should work, but for me it did not.
For some reasons the query crashes with the error that the database is corrupt.

In the end I perfomed a query, where I ordered on my field DESCENDING, and using setFetchLim it:1. Its not perfect, but at least it worked.

Also I made sure the field I use has an index.
Since I have few records, this works fine.
On 30000 records, it might be a problem though.

I followed the IOS documentation, fot fatch a "max:" query, but only got "database corrupted" errors. That is the sample code from Apple fails BADLY.

Googling the internet, it seem the call to setPropertiesToFetch fails in IOS 5+ ??!
I have not found any way around that.

Using a normal query, it worked without any issue.
So I must conclude Apple code is no longer corerct.